# Understanding Skorokhod representation of a random variable with prescribed distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation

The following is from Williams' *Probability with Martingales* section 3.12 (I paraphrase a bit):

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ have properties
>
> 1. $F$ is non-decreasing.
> 2. $F$ is normalized.
> 3. $F$ is right-continuous.

> We can construct a random variable with distribution function $F$ carried by $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],\lambda)$ where $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure. Define
> $$X^-(\omega) := \inf\{ z:F(z)\ge\omega\} = \sup\{y:F(y)< \omega\}.$$
> We show $X^-$ is a random variables with $F$ as a distribution function:
> $$\omega\le F(c) \implies X^-(\omega)\le c 
> \ \ \ \ \text{ by definition}$$
> $$X^-(\omega)<z \implies \omega\le F(z) 
> \ \ \ \ \text{ by ?}$$
> $$X^-(\omega)\le c \implies \omega\le F(X^-(\omega))\le F(c) 
> \ \ \ \ \text{ by right-continuity of $F$}$$
> $$\omega\le F(c) \iff X^-(\omega)\le c
> \ \ \ \ \text{ by previous lines}$$
> $$\lambda(X^-\le c) = F(c). 
> \ \ \ \ \text{ by ?}$$
> where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

My questions:

- How are the lines
  $$X^-(\omega)<z \implies \omega\le F(z)$$
  $$\lambda(X^-\le c) = F(c)$$
  derived?
- On which spaces is the random variable $X^-$ defined? It seems that the domain is the probability triple $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],\lambda)$, but what measurable space comprises the codomain?

Comment: If $a >\inf S$ then $a >s$ for some $s \in S$. This should answer your first question. The second one follows from the fact that Lebesgue measure of $[0,c]$ is $c$.

Comment: @geetha290krm that does explain the first question! Thank you. But could you perhaps elaborate on how $\lambda[0,c]=c$ explains the second?

Comment: Lebesgue measure of $\{\omega \in [0,1]: \omega \le c\}=c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $u$ and $x$

Let $u\leq F(x)$. Then as $X^{-}(u)=\inf\{x:F(x)\geq u\}$ we have that $X^{-}(u)\leq x$ as $x$ satisfies that $F(x)\geq u$.

Now let $X^{-}(u)< x$ . Then by property of infimum, there exists $a$ such that $F(a)\geq u$ and $a<x$

Thus by monotonicity, $F(x)\geq F(a)\geq u$ .

But you also have that since $X^{-}(u)$ is the infimum, there exists a sequence $y_{n}$ such that $y_{n}\downarrow X^{-}(u)$ and $F(y_{n})\geq u$.

Thus, by right continuity, you have by taking limits $F(X^{-}(u))\geq u$.

Thus you have the two sided statement : $X^{-}(u)\leq x \iff u\leq F(x)$

Now note that $X^{-}$ is a Random Variable, i.e. real valued measurable function from the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ to $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B})$

The codomain is just $\Bbb{R}$. Note that codomain need not come equipped with a "measure". But as $X^{-}$ is a random variable, it induces a probability distribution $\mu$ on $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B})$

i.e. $\mu((-\infty,t]):=P\bigg((X^{-})^{-1}((-\infty,t]))\bigg)=\lambda\bigg\{\omega\in[0,1]:X^{-}(\omega)\leq t\bigg\}$

Now you use what was shown, $\lambda\bigg\{\omega\in [0,1]:X^{-}(\omega)\leq t\bigg\}=\lambda\bigg\{\omega\in [0,1]:\omega\leq F(t)\bigg\}$.

What does the expression $\bigg\{\omega\in [0,1]:\omega\leq F(t)\bigg\}$ mean? Well, it is simply the interval $[0,F(t)]$ which has Lebesgue measure $F(t)$.

Thus $\mu(-\infty,t]=F(t)$ . So the random variable $X^{-}$ has $\mu$ as the distribution which has cdf given by $F$.

This $X^{-}$ is called the Generalized Inverse of $F$. This gives you a random variable defined on $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ such that it has same distribution as $F$.